# SignalR subscribe all hubs/methods at once

Tags: javascript, signalr

I'd like to make a simple wrapper for SignalR on clientside. It basically should have method `send(hubName, methodName, args)` and trigger some kind of `callback(hubName, methodName, args)` without explicit subscription to specific hubs.

Is there an easy way to do it or i should dig into `jquery.signalR`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to be something like that:

```
function send(hub, method, args) {
    $.signalR.hub.send({
        H: method,
        M: method,
        A: args,
        I: requestId++ // some global var which increments with every request
    });
}

$.signalR.hub.received(function(resp) {
    if (resp.I) {
        const requestId = resp.I;
        const response = resp.R;
        console.log('Response received', requestId, response);
    } else {
        const hub = resp.H;
        const method = resp.M;
        const args = resp.A;
        console.log('Server sent event received', hub, method, args);
    }
});
```

`I` is kind of request counter. It's included in responses for corresponding requests.